# how to sort a CSV using basic Python modules only

Tags: python-3.x, csv, sorting, leaderboard

so, me and a friend are working on a game built in python, and we're working on a leaderboard system, but having trouble getting the CSV file to order itself when called.
we were using a dedicated python file to attempt to work on opening the external file, but we cannot work out how to make it order.

```
import csv
import operator
with open('leaderboard.csv', 'r') as f:
     csv1 = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
     for row in csv1:
        if row:
            some=row[1]
            print(row)
```

our code looks like that.
Any help?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sort things in Python with the built-in `sorted` function or the `list.sort` method.  `csv.reader(source, ...)` returns an iterator of lists of strings, which can be passed to `sorted`.

```
import csv
data = ('c cee', 'a aaa', 'z zee')
for row in sorted(csv.reader(data)):
    print(row)
```

prints

```
['a aaa']
['c cee']
['z zee']
```

Pass a key function to sorted to sort the lists on a different field.  See the `sorted` doc.

Comment: the only problem I see here is that we need a code that orders the numbers in a CSV (row 2 of the leaderboard) and this orders the names alphabetically instead (row 1)

Comment: Your comment gives the impression that your table is transposed from the normal structure, with 2 rows - the first with names and the second with numbers.  Is the number a score for the name above, and do you want to order the names by score?

Comment: yes. The table would have the first row having the name, and the 2nd having the score, and we want it to sort the name by which has the highest score.